# Android Studio on Lenovo Chromebook glitchy Installer

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX6yU.png)

(Ignore the discord page)

Essentially just the only issue that I'm having is that I can't agree to this thing that it wants me to because it's glitched off-screen and I can't move the page to agree.

Try help me fix this :)